# Centralizers of elementary abelian subgroups of $p$-groups

Tags: p-groups, centralisers

Let $P$ be a $p$-group. It is known that if $E$ is a maximal elementary abelian subgroup of rank 2 in $P$, then $C_P(E)/E$ is cyclic where $C_P(E)$ denotes the centralizer of $E$ in $P$.
This is proved, for example, in the paper by Jon Carlson and Jacques Thevenaz on the endotrivial modules.

I wonder if there is such a general result for any elementary abelian subgroup?

Comment: By maximal here, you mean that $E$ is elementary abelian of rank $2$, and there are no larger elementary abelian subgroups?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean by maximal.

Comment: Do you still want the subgroup to be maximal (with respect to being elementary abelian)? Otherwise, You will certainly not get them to have cyclic quotients.

Comment: Can anyone give a precise reference to the Carlson-Thevenaz paper (I didn't manage to find it in there)? Another question: Isn't $P=\mathbb{Z}/4\times \mathbb{Z}/4$, $E=\mathbb{Z}/2\times \mathbb{Z}/2$ a counterexample?